# не происходит соединение по websocket

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, django-channels

Есть сервер `nginx` c такими настройками

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream uwsgi {
     server unix:/docker_api/app.sock; # for a file socket
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # порт, который будет слушать веб-сервер в ожидании запросов от пользователей
    listen    80;
    # index  index.html;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    # # доменное имя
    server_name  1.1.1.1;


    root /var/evners;
    underscores_in_headers on;
    charset     utf-8;

    # максимальный размер загружаемых на сервер данных
    client_max_body_size 75M;


    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://1.1.1.1:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    }

    #index обслуживание медиа файлов и статики
     location /media  {
         alias /docker_api/media;  # расположение медиафайлов (при необходимости измените)
     }

    location /static {
        alias /docker_api/static; # расположение статики (при необходимости измените)
    }

    # Остальные запросы перенаправляются в Django приложение
    location /api {
        uwsgi_pass  uwsgi;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # файл uwsgi_params
    }

    # Остальные запросы перенаправляются в Django приложение
    location /auth {
        uwsgi_pass  uwsgi;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # файл uwsgi_params
    }

    location / {
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        sendfile on;
        sendfile_max_chunk 1m;

    }
}
```

на сервере запущены 4 контейнера `docker`:

```
 `CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
3e00dd730b88        docker_nginx_evners    "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   4 hours ago         Up 30 minutes       0.0.0.0:80-81->80-81/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   nginx_evners
406edb8bd201        docker_django_evners   "uwsgi --ini uwsgi.i…"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp                           django_evners
ce5a7401d7cc        postgres:10            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   33 hours ago        Up 6 hours          0.0.0.0:7433->5432/tcp                           postgres_evner
112fbb88616f        redis:latest           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   33 hours ago        Up 6 hours          0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp                           redis_evner`</pre></code>
```

В *django* использую `django-channnels`. При запуске в `pycharm` фронта (`vue.js`) и сервера всё работает без ошибок. При `deploy` на реальном боевом сервере ошибка

> WebSocket connection to ws://12.12.12.12/ws/chat/1/ failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

.

Comment: Я не совсем понял, где у вас вебсокет-то находится? Точно на `http://1.1.1.1:8000`, а не на `uwsgi`?

Comment: хорошее замечание, я что-то и сам запутался. django-channels запущен в контейнере, в нём как раз и запущено 4 процесса uwsgi. что-то я не так настроил?можете подсказать как следует сделать?